# create new case when case comment added after 10 days

Tags: case, comments

When a community user adds a comment to a closed case after 10 days of closure, i want it to create a new case record.Once an agent has closed a case, sometime the users take a while and then come back with a case comment but i want these to create a new case and reference aspects of the old case values
I have created a process builder but used `CaseComment.Parent.CreatedBy.ProfileId` and this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What specifically have you tried? Please show us your Process, and give a detailed description of how it behaves. (See [ask]).

Comment: IIRC ProfileId is only accessible if the user context this runs under has access to setup.

Comment: You probably would want to create a flow. I suppose you already capture a Case Close Date, when you receive a case comment you may want to capture that date as well. fetch these records and store them in variables. Use wait element on your conditions based on the number of days since the new comment is received on a closed case and then create a case if it meets the criteria.